# How to join two unequal table using sql?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to find out the country of each soccer player. I have two tables one is the player table and the other is the country.
I am using google colab to execute SQL queries. in the following query have tried to see the player table.

`pd.read_sql("select * from player", conn)`

```
    id  player_api_id   player_name player_fifa_api_id  birthday    height  weight
    1   505942  Aaron Appindangoye  218353  1992-02-29 00:00:00 182.88  187
    2   155782  Aaron Cresswell 189615  1989-12-15 00:00:00 170.18  146
    3   162549  Aaron Doran 186170  1991-05-13 00:00:00 170.18  163
    4   30572   Aaron Galindo   140161  1982-05-08 00:00:00 182.88  198
    5   23780   Aaron Hughes    17725   1979-11-08 00:00:00 182.88  154
    ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
    11071   26357   Zoumana Camara  2488    1979-04-03 00:00:00 182.88  168
    11072   111182  Zsolt Laczko    164680  1986-12-18 00:00:00 182.88  176
    11073   36491   Zsolt Low   111191  1979-04-29 00:00:00 180.34  154
    11074   35506   Zurab Khizanishvili 47058   1981-10-06 00:00:00 185.42  172
    11075   39902   Zvjezdan Misimovic  102359  1982-06-05 00:00:00 180.34  176
 rows × 7 columns
```

The second table which is the country table can be seen in the following.

`pd.read_sql("select * from country", conn)`

```
id     country_name
1       Belgium
1729    England
4769    France
7809    Germany
10257   Italy
13274   Netherlands
15722   Poland
17642   Portugal
19694   Scotland
21518   Spain
24558   Switzerland
```

I have tried to use left join but it didn't work for me. here i want to create another column that show the country of each player using both table. It would be great if you could help me in this.

I have tried to join both table using left join using following queries.

`pd.read_sql("select player.id, player.player_name, player.birthday, country.country_name from player left join country on country.id=player.id", conn)`

and I got the unexpected table where only first row have country name while rest of them are None.

```
    id  player_name         birthday            Country_name
    1   Aaron Appindangoye  1992-02-29 00:00:00 Belgium
    2   Aaron Cresswell 1989-12-15 00:00:00     None
    3   Aaron Doran 1991-05-13 00:00:00         None
    4   Aaron Galindo   1982-05-08 00:00:00     None
    5   Aaron Hughes    1979-11-08 00:00:00     None
    ... ... ... ...
    11071   Zoumana Camara  1979-04-03 00:00:00 None
    11072   Zsolt Laczko    1986-12-18 00:00:00 None
    11073   Zsolt Low   1979-04-29 00:00:00 None
    11074   Zurab Khizanishvili 1981-10-06 00:00:00 None
    11075   Zvjezdan Misimovic  1982-06-05 00:00:00 None
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: The player table doesn't appear to have any column which is a foreign key for the country.

Comment: Tim is correct. What is the column in the first table that is the Foreign key of the second table? Your problem seems to be joining the incorrect column

Comment: @Mohd Aziz; Does your player table has any column with conutry_id or something ?
If it is not there;
It's impossible to find players' country

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting Belguim for the first player is because the first player's value for the **player_id** column is **1** and the **id** column in the country table for Belgium is 1. So the JOIN gets Belguim.

You then get none for the second (and subsequent rows) because the **player_id** (2 for   Aaron Cresswell) does not have a value (2   Aaron Cresswell) in the **id** column of the country table. So the JOIN gets nothing.

You need an extra column in the player table for the value that corresponds to the country.

So instead of something along the lines of:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  player_api_id INTEGER,   player_name TEXT, player_fifa_api_id INTEGER,  birthday TEXT,    height REAL,  weight INTEGER)
```

You want something like:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, PLAYER_COUNTRY_ID INTEGER /*>>>>> Optional */REFERENCES country(id),  player_api_id INTEGER,   player_name TEXT, player_fifa_api_id INTEGER,  birthday TEXT,    height REAL,  weight INTEGER)
```

Now if the following were used to insert the player data (after the country data, if the optional Foreign Key constraint is used):-

```
 INSERT INTO player VALUES
    (1,1 /*Belgium*/   ,505942,  'Aaron Appindangoye',  218353,  '1992-02-29 00:00:00', 182.88,  187),
    (2,4769 /* France*/,   155782,  'Aaron Cresswell', 189615,  '1989-12-15 00:00:00', 170.18,  146),
    (3, 13274,   162549,  'Aaron Doran', 186170,  '1991-05-13 00:00:00', 170.18,  163),
    (4,1729,   30572,   'Aaron Galindo',   140161,  '1982-05-08 00:00:00', 182.88,  198),
    (5,1729,   23780,   'Aaron Hughes',    17725,   '1979-11-08 00:00:00', 182.88,  154),
    /*... ... ... ... ... ... ...*/
    (11071,10257,   26357,   'Zoumana Camara',  2488,    '1979-04-03 00:00:00', 182.88,  168),
    (11072,7809,   111182,  'Zsolt Laczko'    ,164680,  '1986-12-18 00:00:00', 182.88,  176),
    (11073,17642,   36491,   'Zsolt Low',   111191,  '1979-04-29 00:00:00', 180.34,  15),
    (11074,21518,   35506,   'Zurab Khizanishvili', 47058,   '1981-10-06 00:00:00', 185.42,  172),
    (11075,24558,   39902,   'Zvjezdan Misimovic',  102359,  '1982-06-05 00:00:00', 180.34,  176)
;
```

- i.e. your data BUT with the country id added as the second value.

With a slightly modified query as per:-

```
select player.id, player.player_name, player.birthday, country.country_name from player left join country on country.id=/*player.id*/ player_country_id;
```

- note the commented out `player.id`

And the result:-

[image]

- the countries are very unlikely to affect the real-life countries